# In a photoelectric cell, how come the electrons don't move to the higher potential through the vacuum without the need of an incident light?

Tags: vacuum, photoelectric-effect, photon-emission

I have been reading about the photoelectric effect and I have arrived at the photoelectric cell. Knowing that the air is removed from inside the cell, and assuming there's no incident light. How come the electrons don't jump the gap as soon as there's a potential difference between the anode and the cathode? As in, let's say, a vacuum tube?

[image]

Comment: Please look up “work function”.

Comment: In a vacuum tube, you need a heated filament to boil off the electrons. The high temperature allows electrons to overcome the work function.